# Mysql show multiple table by id

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

I have a table with search by filter  and here are my table data: ID,name, country, and link.

After the search when the customer will have a result with a person with id 1, name, country and **link**, I want that, when is clicking on link to redirect by **id** to a custom page with this table + 2 more, with foreign key from the first table,

For example: students - he will search by name, the result will have:
1, John, America, link --> when he press on like I need to go on a page redirected by his id and have there: his data: 1, john, american + exams table with date, exam title, location, etc.

My question is:

How can I set a PHP page to show me 2 tables joined by id on link after the search result?

Comment: what's the *real* question?

Comment: How can i set a php page to show me 2 tables joined by id on link after the search result.

Comment: check this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: @Razvanhoratiu that makes more sense than what you typed for your original question; can you update your question so it is more clear? I think you'd be more likely to get help.

Comment: ok so when i search for a student, it's show me a table result, at the end of the table i have a link data into row, the question is: how can i make when i press the link button to show me the initial table of student + another table with exams details of that student ( by id )  http://s30.postimg.org/vst8rnb9t/link.jpg   http://s10.postimg.org/oow22zpw9/table.jpg